# Pytesseract or Keras OCR to extract text from image

Tags: keras, deep-learning, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract text from images. Currently I'm getting empty string as output. Below is my code for pytesseract, although I'm open to Keras OCR also:-

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

path = 'captcha.svg.png'
img = Image.open(path)
captchaText = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
```

I wasn't sure how to work with svg image so I converted them to png. Below are a few sample image:-

[image: SVG image converted to PNG]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1 (2021-05-19):** I'm able to convert svg to png using cairosvg. Still not able to read the captcha text

**Edit 2 (2021-05-20):** Keras OCR is also not returning anything for these images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for [`keras-ocr`](https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr) not working or returning nothing is because of the grayscale image (as I found it worked otherwise). See below:

```
from PIL import Image 

a = Image.open('/content/gD7vA.png') # return none by keras-ocr, 
a.mode, a.split() # mode 1 channel + transparent layer / alpha layer (LA)

b = Image.open('/content/CYegU.png') # return result by keras-ocr
b.mode, b.split() # mode RGB + transparent layer / alpha layer (RGBA)
```

In the above, the `a` is the file you mention in your question; as It showed, it has to channel, e.g. grayscale and transparent layer. And `b` is the file I converted to `RGB` or `RGBA`. The transparent layer already included in your original file and I didn't remove it, but it seems useless to keep otherwise if needed. In short, to make your input work on [`keras-ocr`](https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr), you can convert your files to `RGB` (or `RGBA`) first and save them on disk. And then pass them to ocr.

```
# Using PIL to convert one mode to another 
# and save on disk
c = Image.open('/content/gD7vA.png').convert('RGBA')
c.save(....png)
c.mode, c.split()

('RGBA',
 (<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=150x50 at 0x7F03E8E7A410>,
  <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=150x50 at 0x7F03E8E7A590>,
  <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=150x50 at 0x7F03E8E7A810>,
  <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=150x50 at 0x7F03E8E7A110>))
```

---

**Full code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# keras-ocr will automatically download pretrained
# weights for the detector and recognizer.
pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()

# Get a set of three example images
images = [
         keras_ocr.tools.read(url) for url in [
            '/content/CYegU.png', # mode: RGBA; Only RGB should work too!
            '/content/bw6Eq.png', # mode: RGBA; 
            '/content/jH2QS.png', # mode: RGBA
            '/content/xbADG.png'  # mode: RGBA
    ]
]

# Each list of predictions in prediction_groups is a list of
# (word, box) tuples.
prediction_groups = pipeline.recognize(images)
Looking for /root/.keras-ocr/craft_mlt_25k.h5
Looking for /root/.keras-ocr/crnn_kurapan.h5
```

```
prediction_groups
[[('zum', array([[ 10.658852,  15.11916 ],
          [148.90204 ,  13.144257],
          [149.39563 ,  47.694347],
          [ 11.152428,  49.66925 ]], dtype=float32))],
 [('sresa', array([[  5.,  15.],
          [143.,  15.],
          [143.,  48.],
          [  5.,  48.]], dtype=float32))],
 [('sycw', array([[ 10.,  15.],
          [149.,  15.],
          [149.,  49.],
          [ 10.,  49.]], dtype=float32))],
 [('vdivize', array([[ 10.407883,  13.685192],
          [140.62648 ,  16.940662],
          [139.82323 ,  49.070583],
          [  9.604624,  45.815113]], dtype=float32))]]
```

**Display**

```
# Plot the predictions
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(images), figsize=(20, 20))
for ax, image, predictions in zip(axs, images, prediction_groups):
    keras_ocr.tools.drawAnnotations(image=image, predictions=predictions, ax=ax)
```

[image]